# Text EditにDrag & Dropでテキストファイルを表示したい。(Qt Creatorにて）

Tags: qt5, qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator3.3.1でアプリ開発の勉強中です。

Googleで調べたのですが、見つからないのでヘルプがほしいと思い質問します。

Text EditにDrag & Dropでテキストファイルを表示したいと考えております。
dragEnterEvent、dropEventを使えばできるっぽいというところまでは調べました。

プロジェクト作成時に作られるQMainWindowから派生したクラスはこの２つのメソッド
がでてくるのですが、*.uiに配置したText Editに対してdragEnterEvent、dropEventを
つなげればよいかがわからずに苦戦しております。

どうしたら*.uiに配置したText Editに対してDrag & Dropでテキストファイルを表示
させることができるかを教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、`QTextEdit`のサブクラスを作成します。

**mytextedit.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MYTEXTEDIT_H
#define MYTEXTEDIT_H

#include <QTextEdit>

class MyTextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTextEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
};

#endif // MYTEXTEDIT_H
```

**mytextedit.cpp**

```cpp
#include "mytextedit.h"
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QFile>

MyTextEdit::MyTextEdit(QWidget *parent) :
   QTextEdit(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void MyTextEdit::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (!event->mimeData()->urls().empty())
        event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void MyTextEdit::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QFile file(event->mimeData()->urls().first().toLocalFile());
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    setPlainText(file.readAll());
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

次に、フォームエディタで`*.ui`上に配置された`QTextEdit`をこのサブクラスに**格上げ**します。
フォームエディタ上で配置した`QTextEdit`を右クリックすると「格上げ先を選択...」という項目が表示されるはずです。

[image: ScreenShot]

このダイアログで`MyTextEdit`を「追加」し、「格上げ」を行うとDrag & Dropに対応したTextEditを使うことができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すぐに試すことはできませんが、後で試してみます。